# Percent change difference for time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to calculate percent change from time = 1 for variables 'wt' and 'wc' at time 1, time 2 and time 3. At time 1 it will be 0. At time 2 it will look something like this percent change in 'wt' at t2 = t2-t1/t1*100 and t3 it should look like 'wt' = t3-t1/t1*100. I would then like to add this as a new variable to the existing excel data sheet. I tried looking for other examples but none of them matched with my data format. Thanks!

```
structure(list(code = c(100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 
102), treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), time = c(1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), wt = c(80, 78, 76, 75, 74, 74, 78, 74, 
72), wc = c(90, 89, 87, 92, 91, 90, 89, 86, 84)), .Names = c("code", 
"treatment", "time", "wt", "wc"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
class =c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to follow the suggestion below. But I am getting an error

```
> data <- read.csv("All Data with BMI and other tweaks.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(data)
 [1] "code"           "treatment"      "age"            "sex"           
 [5] "time"           "bicep"          "tricep"         "subscapular"   
 [9] "suprailiac"     "weight"         "pwc"            "wc"            
[13] "bia"            "height"         "bmi"            "wthr"          
[17] "density"        "X.fat"          "fm"             "ffm"           
[21] "dietary.recall" "reportingdate"  "NumFoods"       "NumCodes"      
[25] "kcal"           "prot"           "tfat"           "carb"          
[29] "mois"           "alc"            "caff"           "theo"          
[33] "sugr"           "fibe"           "calc"           "iron"          
[37] "magn"           "phos"           "pota"           "sodi"          
[41] "zinc"           "copp"           "sele"           "vc"            
[45] "vb1"            "vb2"            "niac"           "vb6"           
[49] "fola"           "fa"             "ff"             "fdfe"          
[53] "vb12"           "vara"           "ret"            "bcar"          
[57] "acar"           "cryp"           "lyco"           "lz"            
[61] "atoc"           "vk"             "vitd"           "choln"         
[65] "chole"          "sfat"           "s040"           "s060"          
[69] "s080"           "s100"           "s120"           "s140"          
[73] "s160"           "s180"           "mfat"           "m161"          
[77] "m181"           "m201"           "m221"           "pfat"          
[81] "p182"           "p183"           "p184"           "p204"          
[85] "p205"           "p225"           "p226"           "vite_add"      
[89] "b12_add"        "datacomp"      
> library(dplyr)
> data <- data %>%
+ group_by(code) %>%
+ mutate(wt.pch = (data$weight - data$weight[1]) / data$weight * 100, wc.pch = (data$wc - data$wc[1]) / data$wc[1] * 100)
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `wt.pch` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 114
```

Comment: By t2 - t1 / 100 * 100 do you mean (t2 - t1 / 100) * 100? Looks strange. I'd guess it should be (t2 - t1) / t1 * 100.

Comment: @Julius you are right. I made a mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(wt.pch = (wt - wt[1]) / wt[1] * 100, 
                                 wc.pch = (wc - wc[1]) / wc[1] * 100)
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   code [3]
#    code treatment  time    wt    wc wt.pch wc.pch
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1   100      1.00  1.00  80.0  90.0   0      0   
# 2   100      1.00  2.00  78.0  89.0  -2.50  -1.11
# 3   100      1.00  3.00  76.0  87.0  -5.00  -3.33
# 4   101      2.00  1.00  75.0  92.0   0      0   
# 5   101      2.00  2.00  74.0  91.0  -1.33  -1.09
# 6   101      2.00  3.00  74.0  90.0  -1.33  -2.17
# 7   102      1.00  1.00  78.0  89.0   0      0   
# 8   102      1.00  2.00  74.0  86.0  -5.13  -3.37
# 9   102      1.00  3.00  72.0  84.0  -7.69  -5.62
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted to do. How do I edit these new variables into the excel file?

Comment: @DiscoR, if `res` has the result, you may export it with, e.g., `write.csv(res, "file.csv")`.

Comment: sorry if I am not being clear. I already have a file with this data called 'all data'. I would like to add two new percent variables to that file based on the data in the same file.

Comment: @DiscoR, so what about loading your file, running this code, in this way producing two additional columns, and then exporting everything back? There are no standard ways to just paste extra values in an existing excel sheet. If you do want something nonstandard, I suggest posting a new question. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but ran into an error. Please see the main post for the details.

Comment: I was able to do it! I used the lag function mentioned in the other comment and found another source on how to save it on excel! Thanks!

Comment: @DiscoR, the error in the main post is writing `data$` inside of `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(code) %>% 
    mutate(pct_change_wt = ((wt - lag(wt))/ lag(wt)) * 100,
           pct_change_wc = ((wc - lag(wc))/ lag(wc)) * 100)

print(df)

   code treatment  time    wt    wc pct_change_wt pct_change_wc
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1   100      1.00  1.00  80.0  90.0         NA            NA   
2   100      1.00  2.00  78.0  89.0        - 2.50        - 1.11
3   100      1.00  3.00  76.0  87.0        - 2.56        - 2.25
4   101      2.00  1.00  75.0  92.0         NA            NA   
5   101      2.00  2.00  74.0  91.0        - 1.33        - 1.09
6   101      2.00  3.00  74.0  90.0          0           - 1.10
7   102      1.00  1.00  78.0  89.0         NA            NA   
8   102      1.00  2.00  74.0  86.0        - 5.13        - 3.37
9   102      1.00  3.00  72.0  84.0        - 2.70        - 2.33
```

Explanation:

1.`group_by` on code ensures that we calculate percentage change for each group. 
2.`lag` function takes the previous value within each group.