# Percental Change in Time Series Data

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I just want to generate a variable that captures the relative decline of a variable (v2x_polyarchy) from year to year.This is what my data frame 'episodes_demreg' basically looks like:

```
country_name year   demreg_id  v2x_polyarchy
<chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>   
Suriname     1974   1          0.536 
Suriname     1975   1          0.375
Suriname     1979   2          0.713
Suriname     1980   2          0.226
Suriname     1990   3          0.743
Suriname     1991   3          0.455
```

Based on the suggestion on very similar thread ([Percent change difference for time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352012/percent-change-difference-for-time-series-data)) I tried it like this:

```
episodes_demreg <- episodes_demreg %>%
  group_by(demreg_id) %>%
  mutate (decline_year_relative = ((v2x_polyarchy - lag(v2x_polyarchy)) / lag(v2x_polyarchy)) * 100)
```

However, this does not work, as it results in the value '0' for each observation. Going back and forth revealed that obviously 'lag' does not work and indeed it subtracts the observation of the same row and NOT the row before. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: include the output of `dput(episodes_demreg)` in the question. Check out this link [MRE]

Comment: You won't get the difference between years if you are grouping by year. All the mutate calculations will take a little subsetted data frame with just a single year in it (that's what `group_by` does).

Comment: It's also the same when I do not group by year additionally. I unintentionally left it in the thread, sorry.

Comment: Your code should provide the percental change after grouping by `demreg_id`. If you believe `lag` is not working correctly, what does `lag(c(1,2,3))` output?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers the output is 
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 2 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `lag` from the `stats` package, while you want to use `lag`from the `dplyr` package.

You can either specify the package when calling `lag`

```
  group_by(demreg_id) %>%
  mutate (decline_year_relative = ((v2x_polyarchy - dplyr::lag(v2x_polyarchy)) / dplyr::lag(v2x_polyarchy)) * 100)
```

or set `dplyr` as the default package to use `lag`

```
lag <- dplyr::lag
```